# Getting HIVE_CURSOR_ERROR while querying the table in Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, amazon-athena

Looks like it's a known issue, but my scenario is a little bit different. The data source of my Athena table is a s3 bucket, and I have crawler job reads against it to build the table. Serde serialization lib is set as `org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe` automatically.

Besides fixing it, I'm also wonder how I could find which entry or s3 file caused this problem. Because I can't manually check s3 file by file, it's too huge, and I can't query Athena. Thanks.

Error message:

```
HIVE_CURSOR_ERROR: Row is not a valid JSON Object - JSONException: Illegal escape. at 99 [character 100 line 1]
```

Comment: update: I was able to skip those bad data by solution here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=881557 but still have no idea about how to identify where was wrong

Answer (score 1):

You could ignore malformed json, this would ensure that you can query the table, as described in the [Best Practices for Reading JSON Data by AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/parsing-JSON.html):

```
...
 ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
 WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('ignore.malformed.json' = 'true')
 LOCATION 's3://bucket/path/';
```

I would start with this to ensure that at least some data can be read.

Athena also offers to show the underlying file of a record by using [`"$path"`](https://aws.amazon.com/de/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/find-s3-source-file-athena-table-row/):

```
SELECT "$path" FROM "my_database"."my_table"
```

This might open the possbilities to check how many rows every file has and then check which file can't be fully read by Athena.